# CKEditor5 custom build toolbar is not showing (react)

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I am trying to implement a custom build CKEditor(5) in React, I have added the required plugins and all. Editor is loading properly but the toolbar is missing.
I am able to console the plugin list and toolbar items correctly. But its not showing.

App.js

```
import {CKEditor} from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react";
import CustomEditor from "ckeditor-custom-config/build/ckeditor";

function App() {
  return (
    <CKEditor
          editor={CustomEditor}
          data="<p>Hello from CKEditor 5!</p>"
          onReady={editor => {
            console.log("Editor is ready to use!", editor);
            console.log(
              "toolbar: ",
              Array.from(editor.ui.componentFactory.names())
            );
            console.log(
              "plugins: ",
              CustomEditor.builtinPlugins.map(plugin => plugin.pluginName)
            );
          }}
          onChange={(event, editor) => {
            const data = editor.getData();
            console.log({ event, editor, data });
          }}
          onBlur={editor => {
            console.log("Blur.", editor);
          }}
          onFocus={editor => {
            console.log("Focus.", editor);
          }}
        />
  );
}

export default App;
```

CKEditor build

```
import DecoupledDocumentEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-decoupled/src/decouplededitor.js';
import Alignment from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment/src/alignment.js';
import Autoformat from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-autoformat/src/autoformat.js';
import AutoImage from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/autoimage.js';
import AutoLink from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-link/src/autolink.js';
import BlockQuote from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-block-quote/src/blockquote.js';
import Bold from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/bold.js';
import CKFinderUploadAdapter from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-adapter-ckfinder/src/uploadadapter.js';
import CloudServices from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-cloud-services/src/cloudservices.js';
import Essentials from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials/src/essentials.js';
import FontBackgroundColor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-font/src/fontbackgroundcolor.js';
import FontColor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-font/src/fontcolor.js';
import FontFamily from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-font/src/fontfamily.js';
import FontSize from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-font/src/fontsize.js';
import Heading from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-heading/src/heading.js';
import Image from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/image.js';
import ImageCaption from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/imagecaption.js';
import ImageResize from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/imageresize.js';
import ImageStyle from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/imagestyle.js';
import ImageToolbar from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/imagetoolbar.js';
import ImageUpload from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/imageupload.js';
import Indent from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-indent/src/indent.js';
import IndentBlock from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-indent/src/indentblock.js';
import Italic from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/italic.js';
import Link from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-link/src/link.js';
import List from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-list/src/list.js';
import ListProperties from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-list/src/listproperties.js';
import MediaEmbed from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-media-embed/src/mediaembed.js';
import Paragraph from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paragraph/src/paragraph.js';
import PasteFromOffice from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paste-from-office/src/pastefromoffice.js';
import RemoveFormat from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-remove-format/src/removeformat.js';
import SpecialCharacters from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-special-characters/src/specialcharacters.js';
import SpecialCharactersArrows from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-special-characters/src/specialcharactersarrows.js';
import SpecialCharactersCurrency from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-special-characters/src/specialcharacterscurrency.js';
import SpecialCharactersEssentials from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-special-characters/src/specialcharactersessentials.js';
import SpecialCharactersLatin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-special-characters/src/specialcharacterslatin.js';
import SpecialCharactersMathematical from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-special-characters/src/specialcharactersmathematical.js';
import SpecialCharactersText from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-special-characters/src/specialcharacterstext.js';
import Strikethrough from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/strikethrough.js';
import Subscript from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/subscript.js';
import Superscript from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/superscript.js';
import Table from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-table/src/table.js';
import TableCaption from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-table/src/tablecaption.js';
import TableCellProperties from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-table/src/tablecellproperties';
import TableProperties from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-table/src/tableproperties';
import TableToolbar from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-table/src/tabletoolbar.js';
import TextTransformation from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-typing/src/texttransformation.js';
import TodoList from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-list/src/todolist';
import Underline from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/underline.js';

class Editor extends DecoupledDocumentEditor {}

// Plugins to include in the build.
Editor.builtinPlugins = [
    Alignment,
    Autoformat,
    AutoImage,
    AutoLink,
    BlockQuote,
    Bold,
    CKFinderUploadAdapter,
    CloudServices,
    Essentials,
    FontBackgroundColor,
    FontColor,
    FontFamily,
    FontSize,
    Heading,
    Image,
    ImageCaption,
    ImageResize,
    ImageStyle,
    ImageToolbar,
    ImageUpload,
    Indent,
    IndentBlock,
    Italic,
    Link,
    List,
    ListProperties,
    MediaEmbed,
    Paragraph,
    PasteFromOffice,
    RemoveFormat,
    SpecialCharacters,
    SpecialCharactersArrows,
    SpecialCharactersCurrency,
    SpecialCharactersEssentials,
    SpecialCharactersLatin,
    SpecialCharactersMathematical,
    SpecialCharactersText,
    Strikethrough,
    Subscript,
    Superscript,
    Table,
    TableCaption,
    TableCellProperties,
    TableProperties,
    TableToolbar,
    TextTransformation,
    TodoList,
    Underline
];

// Editor configuration.
Editor.defaultConfig = {
    toolbar: {
        items: [
            'heading',
            '|',
            'fontSize',
            'fontFamily',
            '|',
            'fontColor',
            'fontBackgroundColor',
            '|',
            'bold',
            'italic',
            'underline',
            'strikethrough',
            '|',
            'alignment',
            '|',
            'numberedList',
            'bulletedList',
            '|',
            'outdent',
            'indent',
            '|',
            'todoList',
            'link',
            'blockQuote',
            'imageUpload',
            'insertTable',
            'mediaEmbed',
            '|',
            'superscript',
            'subscript',
            'removeFormat',
            'specialCharacters',
            'undo',
            'redo'
        ]
    },
    language: 'en',
    image: {
        toolbar: [
            'imageTextAlternative',
            'imageStyle:inline',
            'imageStyle:block',
            'imageStyle:side'
        ]
    },
    table: {
        contentToolbar: [
            'tableColumn',
            'tableRow',
            'mergeTableCells',
            'tableCellProperties',
            'tableProperties'
        ]
    }
};

export default Editor;
```

I have also tried to pass the toolbar items directly in the editor like this

```
config={{
        toolbar: {
          items: [
            'heading',
            '|',
            'fontSize',
            'fontFamily',
            '|',
            'fontColor',
            'fontBackgroundColor',
            '|',
            'bold',
            'italic',
            'underline',
            'strikethrough',
            '|',
            'alignment',
            '|',
            'numberedList',
            'bulletedList',
            '|',
            'outdent',
            'indent',
            '|',
            'todoList',
            'link',
            'blockQuote',
            'imageUpload',
            'insertTable',
            'mediaEmbed',
            '|',
            'superscript',
            'subscript',
            'removeFormat',
            'specialCharacters',
            'undo',
            'redo'
          ]
        }
      }}
```

but still, it's not working.
When I replace this custom build with the classic one, it works fine and shows toolbar.
Not sure what's missing while using custom build.

However, I am getting the toolbar items in the console!

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Got this fixed.
When using decoupled editor, we need to add the toolbar to the DOM manually (Works differently from classic editor that's why).

[Find the documentation here](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/getting-started/frameworks/react.html#using-the-document-editor-build)

Thanks.

Comment: Were you able to get it fully working and looking like the decoupled document should look like? At first I had the same "issue" as you had here and found the same part in the documentation. Now everything renders, but it looks just like the classic - a texarea with the toolbar - no "document-like/"paper-like" ui.

Comment: @Tsabary Sorry for the late reply, yes, it looks the same. By the way, is your issue fixed?

Comment: Hi All, Please help how to use custom build. What are the installation steps for custom build